# ffmpeg wrong framerate when converting x264 to x265

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert the video files from my Samsung phone to a more efficient format. Samsung uses x264 with a very high bitrate, instead I am using x265 with the following settings:

```
ffmpeg -i IN.mp4 -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 OUT.mp4
```

However, there seems to be a problem with the framerate. Samsung specifies 60 fps in the metadata, but the video stream shows 29.95 fps.
If I use the above command to convert to x265, it even outputs a stream with 120 fps. ffmpeg also shows the warning "More than 1000 frames duplicated".

How can I keep the original framerate?

Here is the ffmpeg output:

```
ffmpeg -i IN.mp4 -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 OUT.mp4
ffmpeg version N-110223-gb18a9c2971-20230410 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.152_89671bf)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --disable-libmfx --enable-libvpl --enable-openal --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20230410
  libavutil      58.  6.100 / 58.  6.100
  libavcodec     60.  9.100 / 60.  9.100
  libavformat    60.  4.101 / 60.  4.101
  libavdevice    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavfilter     9.  5.100 /  9.  5.100
  libswscale      7.  2.100 /  7.  2.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IN.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2023-03-17T13:51:19.000000Z
    com.android.version: 13
    com.android.capture.fps: 60.000000
  Duration: 00:01:16.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 26864 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 26603 kb/s, 29.95 fps, 120 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-03-17T13:51:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-03-17T13:51:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.5+95-38cf1c379
x265 [info]: build info [Windows][GCC 12.2.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-5 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 16 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 4 / wpp(17 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 3
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias  : 25 / 250 / 40 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / off / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-25.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip mode=1 signhide tmvp
x265 [info]: tools: b-intra strong-intra-smoothing lslices=6 deblock sao
Output #0, mp4, to 'OUT.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    com.android.capture.fps: 60.000000
    com.android.version: 13
    encoder         : Lavf60.4.101
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 120 fps, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-03-17T13:51:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.9.100 libx265
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-03-17T13:51:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
[vost#0:0/libx265 @ 00000249776f1440] More than 1000 frames duplicated40.0kbits/s dup=991 drop=0 speed=0.484x
frame= 9197 fps= 52 q=37.0 Lsize=   32338kB time=00:01:16.61 bitrate=3457.6kbits/s dup=6902 drop=0 speed=0.43x
video:29752kB audio:2393kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:2kB muxing overhead: 0.600966%
x265 [info]: frame I:     79, Avg QP:25.98  kb/s: 25459.52
x265 [info]: frame P:   2332, Avg QP:31.54  kb/s: 9763.15
x265 [info]: frame B:   6786, Avg QP:36.46  kb/s: 653.28
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:5.5% UV:5.3%

encoded 9197 frames in 177.98s (51.68 fps), 3176.26 kb/s, Avg QP:35.12
```